# Google Sign In flow with multiple activities

Tags: android, google-signin

I have an app with 3 activities : a login activity, a main activity and a detail activity.

The login activity uses Google Sign In to get the account of the user (the token id and the email).
Both Main activity and Detail activity need the`GoogleSignInAccount`.

I don't want to the app to always start on login activity and transparently re-login when the user launch back the app.

I don't want to store the token id and the user email on shared preferences, I'd prefer to manipulate directly a`GoogleSignInAccount` everywhere in my app.

What is the proper flow to handle this sign in scenario ? Should I try to do a [`silentSignIn`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInApi.html#public-methods) in every screen or is there a better way to store and retrieve the `GoogleSignInAccount` ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `silentSignIn` for this purpose.

If you are looking for the `GoogleSignInAccount` on UI thread, below is the asynchronous version:

```
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
        new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull GoogleSignInResult result) {
                if (googleSignInResult.isSuccess() {
                    GoogleSignInAccount gsa = googleSignInResult.getSignInAccount();     
                }

            }
        });
```

Note: If your mGoogleApiClient is not built with enableAutoManage, you must manually call mGoogleApiClient.connect() and mGoogleApiClient.disconnect() for above code sample to work. For more details, see more about [managing the GoogleApiClient connection lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client#manually_managed_connections).

Or on a non-UI thread, you can use sample code below:

```
try {
    ConnectionResult result = mGoogleApiClient.blockingConnect();
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult =     
               Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(googleApiClient).await();
        if (googleSignInResult.isSuccess() {
            GoogleSignInAccount gsa = googleSignInResult.getSignInAccount();   
        } 
    } 
} finally { 
   mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
```

Check out the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth) for more details, including using the Google Account ID token for backend auth or API calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass **GoogleSignInAccount** as extra Intent input:

```
GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("singedInAccount", acct);
startActivity(intent);
```

and receive it in *onCreate()* another's activity method as such:

```
getIntent().getParcelableExtra("singedInAccount");
```

Notice that you have to use *getParcelableExtra()* instead of *getSerializableExtra()* as far as [GoogleSignInAccount](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount) implements [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) and not Serializable interface.